# get age brackets and gender filtered by pagepath

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to get the age bracket of users that visit a specific page on my site.

[using this google analytics tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) i set

```
1. dimensions => ga:visitorGender,ga:visitorAgeBracket
2. metrics => ga:users
3. filter => ga:pagePath==/view/?id=85933
4. startDate => 2015-02-26
5. endDate => 2015-03-12
```

The results are `no results found`  When i use a date dimension and a pageview metrics, i get the results for my pagePath. Proves my pagePath is not wrong.

Any idea how to get this to work for both agebrackets and gender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would make sure you have diplayfeatures enabled. That is required for demographics features.

[Instructions to enable Demographic reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en)

If you still can't get the report, I believe the issue is caused by the Demographic's threshold. From [Help Center Article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2954071?hl=en#thresholds)

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from
>   inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a
>   report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or
>   secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold
>   may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For
>   example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a
>   report, then data for the male dimension may be withheld.
>
> If a threshold has been applied to a report, you will see a notice
>   below the report title.

This means that this data will only be shown if there are at least `N` users in that category. It is not clear what `N` stands for.

Comment: thanks, i missed that. it was the Thresholds. on a different `pagePath` with more views, i do get the `ga:visitorGender,ga:visitorAgeBracket` results